# Palindrome checker does not function properly with "almostomla"

Tags: javascript

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  const forward = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "").toUpperCase()
  const reversed = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "").toUpperCase()
  for (let i = 0; i < forward.length; i++) {
    for (let k = reversed.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
      if (forward[i] === reversed[k]) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(palindrome("almostomla"));
```

Why is this not working??
does my loop just creates a new "s"?

Comment: `if(forward[i] === reversed[k]){` it shouldnt return true, it should just continue, and then return true at the end if it finishes both loops

Comment: `forward` and `reversed` are the same, why do you need two variables? `reversed` isn't actually the reverse of anything.

Comment: You shouldn't have nested loops. You're comparing every character with every other character. Except that you return on the first iteration, so you only compare the first and last characters.

Comment: I tried it without nesting loops, it didn't worked.

Comment: BTW observe that while you have two nested loops, you return either true or false right after checking one pair of characters

Comment: I hate to say this but I am new at programming (first month), so I take all your comments as an opportunity to learn, so please explain to me why is it checking one pair?

Comment: If one of the suggested solutions helped, make sure to accept it by clicking the green checkmark, it helps the contributors

Answer (score 1):

You don't need nested loops, that will compare every character with every other character. You just want to compare the first character with the last character, 2nd character with 2nd-to-last character, and so on. So there should just be a single loop that increments `i` and decrements `k` in lock step.

You shouldn't return `true` when you find a match, because there could be later characters that don't match. Return `false` when you find a mismatch, and return `true` if you make it through the loop without returning.

You don't need both `forward` and `reversed` variables, since they're the same. Just convert the input string to uppercase once, and use that for both.

You don't need to iterate through the whole string, you can stop when you get to the middle.

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  const upper = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "").toUpperCase()
  for (let i = 0, k = upper.length - 1; i < upper.length/2; i++, k--) {
    if (upper[i] !== upper[k]) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(palindrome("almostomla"));
console.log(palindrome("almotomla"));
console.log(palindrome("almottomla"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want this:

```
function palindrome(str) {
  const forward = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "").toUpperCase()
  var n = forward.length
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if (forward[i] !== forward[n-i-1]) {
        return false;
      }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Hello matt, Thank you for your help can you please guide me what does [n-i-1] means?

Comment: It represents the mirrored element in the array